# Using Distinct with Top in Select Clause of Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server I am able to create a query that uses both Top and Distinct in the Select clause, such as this one:

```
Select Distinct Top 10 program_name
From sampleTable
```

Will the database return the distinct values from the top 10 results, or will it return the top 10 results of the distinct values? Is this behavior consistent in SQL or is it database dependent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TOP` is executed last, so your `DISTINCT` runs first then the `TOP`

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Select Top 10 program_name
From sampleTable group by program_name;
```

It will return you the top **10 distinct program_name.**

Your query will also return the distinct 10 program_name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct top 10 c from
(
    select 1 c union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 1   union all
    select 2
) as T
order by c
```

Compare that result to these queries:

```
select distinct c from (
    select top 10 c from
    (
        select 1 c union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 2
    ) as T
    order by c
) as T2

select top 10 c from (
    select distinct c from
    (
        select 1 c union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 1   union all
        select 2
    ) as T
) as T2
order by c
```